# How can a Jones vector give linear polarization along an axis?

Tags: optics, polarization

If we represent a [Jones vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus#Jones_vectors) by two complex-valued exponentials, $J_1 = e^{i \phi_1}$ and $J_2 = e^{i \phi_2}$, how can this ever give a polarization along the x-axis? We write such a polarization as $J_1 = 1, J_2 = 0$, but the exponents used can never give a zero value. Nor can we simply use the real component, as the complex phase determines circular or elliptical polarization. Is it just a matter of rotating our basis for, say, $J_1 = 1, J_2 = 1$ to give a polarization along some new x-axis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The component of the Jones vector are not defined as two pure imaginary exponentials but as two **complex numbers** $z_1$ and $z_2$ whose polar decomposition is $z_i=|z_i|e^{i\phi_i}$ for $i=1,2$. To describe linearly polarized light along the $x$ axis

$$ |H \rangle = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we just take $z_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ ($\phi_1=0$) and $z_2=0$. Of course, you can always rotate the basis and consider the rotated axis $x'$ as your new $x$ axis. The case $z_1=z_2=1/\sqrt{2}$ is linearly polarized light along an axis $x'$ which corresponds to the usual $x$ axis rotated by $\theta=\pi/4$.

And for the last question the answer is yes, as long as there is no relative phase between the vector components the light will be linearly polarized.